# Setting error order preferences in filepond

Tags: filepond

Is there a way to set error ordering preferences in filepond? I ran into an issue where the error being thrown is not in the order that I would want an error thrown.

I'm using a filepond with the following two options:

```
maxFileSize: "10MB",
acceptedFileTypes: ['image/png', 'image/jpeg']
```

When I try to drag an mp4 file that is over 10MB, I receive a file-size error. In this scenario I would like to receive an invalid filetype error first. Is it possible to have filepond preference one error over another or is the ordering always set?